# how to manage freeradius clients throught a web client

Tags: networking, server

I have Freeradius running on Ubuntu 12.04 server, to authenticate iBurst clients of my ISP. It is working fine, the only issue is that I don't know how to manage these clients.

For example if a client has not payed to use Internet, I need to be able to disconnect him/her and reconnect him/her once the payment has been done. The only way that I know is to edit the `/etc/freeradius/users` file and comment the `Framed-IP-Address` line which is not easy to do every time. Also, I fear that I might accidentally damage the file if I continue accessing it everyday and modifying it.

I would like to know if there is any other way to do this (preferably through a web client). I found one called *Dialupadmin web interface*, but I don't know if I have to install Freeradius from scratch to be able to use the web interface or if I can just install this and use the existing Freeradius without re-installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use any web management interface like radiusdesk, dialup-admin or dalo-radius.

Those are web management interfaces that allow you to store, delete or update your Freeradius users profiles.

**References:-**
Daloradius: [here](http://poltakjefferson.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/install-freeradius-with-web-based-management-daloradius-on-centosrhel-debian-ubuntu/)
Dialup-admin: [here](http://freeradius.org/dialupadmin.html)